# How to set buttons and EditTextViews horizontally in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am very new in android and present I am learning basic's in android and now I want to set EdittextViews and Buttons like my below image.

For this I have tried to write some code in XML file with my knowledge but I am not able to arrange fields like below image.

Please help me.

In below image "cyan" colors fields are EditTextViews and "red" color fields are Buttons.

### my code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8cff55"
    android:id="@+id/relative">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#cb32ff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#ff2518" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: use GridLayout ... you can get some tutorials of it from youtube

Comment: why here grid layout can't we use here linearlayouts for setting this fields

Comment: yeah you can use but it will become more nested and complex

Comment: can you please post how to set that fields using grid view

Comment: see saeed jassani i set that fields using relative layout and i have one small dought is this screen fit in all devices? i mean tab also

Answer (score 0):

This is a layout I created for my android project.
You can solve your problem by changing some code.

Screenshot:
[image]

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:id="@+id/semesterHead"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:text="semester-1"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_main"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:text="semester-2"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_main"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:text="semester-3"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_main"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:text="semester-4"
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_main"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:text="semester-5"
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_main"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:text="semester-6"
        android:id="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_main"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:text="semester-7"
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_main"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:text="semester-8"
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_main"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: You can either follow my way or use other methods like `GridLayout`, `TableLayout` etc..